# jquery keypress() events are not working for keyup()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code for keypress function, which is allowing only numbers
http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/HkEuf/1/

But, for the same keycodes, keyup function is not working. I mean, if I use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  $("#quantity").keyup(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
});
```

The reason for using keyup is to get the current entered value in the textbox. If I use `keyup` function, I will get the current value. But, If I use keydown or keypress, I am getting the previous or existing value in the textbox
see the updated code with different functions
http://jsfiddle.net/dgireeshraju/HkEuf/7300/
this is the example with keydown, which is giving the existing value.

Comment: why do you want to use keyup not keypress -> use keydown instead

Comment: use .keydown() , if still you want to use keypress i guess you'd have to clear the value before return false;

Answer (score 2):

> Key up fires when the user releases a key, after the default action of that key >has been performed.
>
> Keypress fires when an actual character is being inserted in, for >instance, a text input. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.

`Your code is actaully working in both the cases (you can see the error message atleast )` but since this event are different so is the result. To make it work with `keyup` you need to empty the input element again since by that time the value has already been entered in input element

```
   $("#quantity").keyup(function (e) {
    //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $(this).val(''); //<--- this will empty the value in the input.
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
        return false;
    }
});
```

NOTE: However emptying the input does removes the complete value even when there are numbers in it so, I prefer `keydown` in such cases.

**Updated**

**This is a little hack on input value but (I will still prefer to go with keydown)**, Use this if you really want keyup to work :). since I am modifying the default browser behaviuor, you might also need to think of lots of other cases here.

```
$("#quantity").keyup(function (e) {
//if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
    //display error message
     if(e.which != 13){ //<--- don't remove when entered is pressed.
        $(this).val(e.currentTarget.value.substr(0, e.currentTarget.value.length - 1));
    }
    $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
    return false;
}
console.log(e.currentTarget.value);

});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/7303/)

Comment: $(this).val('') will remove complete value even the value have some number already

Comment: I can use `.keydown`, but `console.log(e.currentTarget.value);` is giving the previous number. I mean, if the textbox already have 2 and I enter 3, it is not showing 23. but shows 2 in the console.log. I want to get the current value in the console.log which is in the textbox. Hope you understand http://jsfiddle.net/dgireeshraju/HkEuf/7300/

Comment: @prashant A little hack should work :).. I actually don't prefer this but ya works ;):):p

Answer (score 2):

`KeyUp` fires after the character inserted only, as you can see your function is actually calling and warning message is displaying.

If you try the same code with `KeyDown` it will work as the event will be called before a character is inserted

```
//called when key is pressed in textbox
  $("#quantity").keydown(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
```

Comment: I can use .keydown, but console.log(e.currentTarget.value); is giving the previous number. I mean, if the textbox already have 2 and I  enter 3, it is not showing 23. but shows 2 in the console.log. I want to get the current value in the console.log which is in the textbox. Hope you understand http://jsfiddle.net/dgireeshraju/HkEuf/7300/

Comment: yeah, this is because when you click 3 and try to log it in key down, it cannot log '3' as it is not inserted yet.